# Celery получает task но не выполняет

Tags: rabbitmq, python-3.7, celery

Проект был на python 3.6, переведя на 3.7 слетел celery. При запуске, task получают но не выполняют.

python3.7 + celery 3.1.25
в терминале:
Received task: app.tasks.send_mail[6aafc459-acd7-463e-bb72-e0ee3ee4ac25]

python3.7 + celery 4.3.0
в терминале:
child process 6536 calling self.run()

celery.py

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'planeks.settings')

app = Celery('mysite')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(['planeks', 'app'])
```

tasks.py

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task()
def send_mail():
    print('test1')
```

celery -A planeks worker -l info

```
[2019-09-11 15:24:20,360: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: app.tasks.send_mail[6aafc459-acd7-463e-bb72-e0ee3ee4ac25]

[2019-09-11 15:24:20,361: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: app.tasks.send_mail[6230c48b-f8fb-4da0-9142-9c79b61e9ec0]

[2019-09-11 15:24:20,362: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: app.tasks.send_mail[e4eed1d1-590b-435b-8017-bda04430d69c]

[2019-09-11 15:24:21,593: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: app.tasks.send_mail[b592745d-0f29-47c6-8206-80d0dde77bfc]

[2019-09-11 15:24:21,595: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: app.tasks.send_mail[90bc4339-8731-4e37-b9d6-de64ce879909]
```

Comment: Если уж вы пробуете ставить Celery 4.3, то не забудьте прочитать историю изменений и информацию о миграции на новую версию и переписать в своём коде все обратно несовместимые изменения: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: Такая же проблема((( И у меня используя rabbitmq-server и последний версии пакета celery 4.4.0 на windows 10

Comment: Мне помог eventlet - pip install eventlet и затем celery -A proj worker -P eventlet. Советую почитать об этом.